# System.BadImageFormatException: Invalid number of sections in declared in PE header

Tags: android, xamarin, android-emulator, maui, .net-maui

I've newly shifted over to developing MAUI Apps and right off the bat, when I create the default MAUI Project and try to execute it on an Android Emulator, I get the following Error:

> Severity  Code    Description Project Path    File    Line    Suppression State
> Error XAPRAS7000  System.BadImageFormatException: Invalid number of
> sections in declared in PE header.    at
> System.Reflection.PortableExecutable.PEHeaders.ReadSectionHeaders(PEBinaryReader&
> reader)    at
> System.Reflection.PortableExecutable.PEHeaders..ctor(Stream peStream,
> Int32 size, Boolean isLoadedImage)    at
> System.Reflection.PortableExecutable.PEReader.InitializePEHeaders()
> at System.Reflection.PortableExecutable.PEReader.GetMetadataBlock()
> at
> System.Reflection.Metadata.PEReaderExtensions.GetMetadataReader(PEReader
> peReader, MetadataReaderOptions options, MetadataStringDecoder
> utf8Decoder)    at
> Xamarin.Android.Tasks.ProcessAssemblies.DeduplicateAssemblies(List`1 output, Dictionary`2 symbols)    at
> Xamarin.Android.Tasks.ProcessAssemblies.RunTask()    at
> Microsoft.Android.Build.Tasks.AndroidTask.Execute() in
> /Users/runner/work/1/s/xamarin-android/external/xamarin-android-tools/src/Microsoft.Android.Build.BaseTasks/AndroidTask.cs:line
> 17    ToDoMaui    C:\Program
> Files\dotnet\packs\Microsoft.Android.Sdk.Windows\32.0.448\targets C:\Program
> Files\dotnet\packs\Microsoft.Android.Sdk.Windows\32.0.448\targets\Microsoft.Android.Sdk.AssemblyResolution.targets    98

However, when I run it as a windows app or on an actual Android device, it works fine. My assumption is that something is messed up with the Android SDK (despite me having it reinstalled).

Comment: have you tried a different Android image?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: @Jason yeah I did, it's the same issue. Perhaps I'll try and reinstall the entire android sdk once again

Comment: And what is the current situation ?

Comment: No positive outcome, It's still the same issue for the Emulator. I ran it as administrator just to be sure, but no luck there either.

Comment: Try to create a new emulator with different API ?

Comment: Well I tried that too, but no luck, I anyways did a factory reset with the OS and reinstalled everything, it's working fine now